How to compile android.jar library with additional logs in few files like Activity.java
I am working on a app where I need to add additional logs in Activity.java and Window.java files. Path of these files inside android.jar is
android.jar!\android\app\Activity.class,
android.jar!\android\view\Window.class.
I have source code of these files in my AOSP at frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/
My question is how can I compile android.jar? Will it get generated in AOSP build? If yes at which path?
Or is there any other way to compile it?
I tried to locate android.jar file after clean build but it is not present in AOSP project.

Please post minimal executing code that demonstrates what you wrote.

You may have some confusion about how Android works. The file android.jar is full of stubbed methods that is used for compilation linking only. If you want to modify Activity.java you need to build AOSP with a target like the emulator and run your app in the emulator. The emulator system image would contain your changes and show up only when you run the emulator, nothing new will appear in android.jar since it is stripped and you don't need to rebuild your app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You will need to compile AOSP for your device / emulator to make those changes live. To do that you need to set up AOSP development environmnet, like explained here, download AOSP source code as specified here, and build for a device / emulator as explained here.
Another option is to use an instrumentation framework like frida to inject your code into specific points in AOSP framework if you can live with AOSP 9 for the sake of your tests. For that you will need to root your device / emulator and install the framework
